# Change app base in bottle to tornado

Tags: python, web-services, tornado, web-frameworks, bottle

My team has developed a website using the bottle as a web service. The issue is that the application has grown, and the simplicity of the bottle is not getting support. What was once simple is getting complicated.

So we decided to change to tornado. The problem is that we do not know how much of code in bottle will have to change to tornado.

So here is the question:

- in the experience of you guys is easy to make this transition from bottle to tornado?
- It is necessary to change a lot of code?
- Or you can merge the two?

Comment: May I ask which aspects are better solved in tornado?

Comment: From what I have researched about the tornado is that it can better deal with several requests. The application that my team is developing will be required for more than 500 machines and more than 50 times per minute.

Comment: For your task - bottle is enough.

Comment: Well... Not wanting to be rude, please do not misunderstand me, I am grateful for your opinion. However, I made three questions, and I'd really like them answered if possible. If I do not supply the correct information, please just ask and I will do everything in my power to provide the necessary information.

Comment: Your question does not have a simple answer. It is easy to make this transition if your code is well designed. You can run bottle app with tornado server.

Comment: I wondered. My research resulted in complex answers and many times I found the answer: "Combine the two." Well, I appreciate the help that was provided.

Answer (score 0):

When my bottle application's load started to create problems, I found using tornado as the underlying web server is a great solution. You can use bottle on top of tornado. Keep all your bottle code, and then tell the tornado server to run it something like this:

```
from bottle import Bottle, get
import tornado.wsgi
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop

app = Bottle()

@app.get('/')
    return 'my great web page'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    container = tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer(app)
    server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(container)
    server.listen(port=80)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Nothing in my bottle app had to change except how the server was launched. Of course, this example is a very simple case.

P.S. I realize this is a necro-post, but hey!